# (MS-DOS, BATCH FILES) How to write to a log file, keeping only the first 1000 recent rows

Tags: batch-file, dos

In Windows Server 2003 environment we have a batch file (*.bat) which writes to text log file in a certain directory.

To prevent from this file to become too big, I would like to know how could I modify the batch file in order to keep only the first 1000 more recent rows.

Thank you in advance for your kind cooperation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call the following routine at any time to trim your log file, preserving only the last 1000 lines. The name of the file is passed as the 1st and only parameter.

```
:KeepLast1000
@echo off
setlocal
set keep=1000
if not exist "%~1" exit /b
set skip=0
for /f  %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<"%~1" 2^>nul') do if %%N gtr %keep% set /a skip=%%N-keep
more +%skip% "%~1" >"%~1.new"
move /y "%~1.new" "%~1" >nul
```